# Why Juggy's spin not damaging roshan or other ancients?

Tags: dota-2, dota

**Spell Description**

Damage type: magical
• This skill won't affect mechanical units.

> If a unit is not being affected by Blade Fury, Yurnero can perform
>   normal attacks against this unit. - Playdota

Roshan is not affected by Bladefury since the damage is magical but there is no normal attacks done to him.

Answer (score 3):

Although he can attack during the Blade Fury, the attacks do no damage to most targets.

Therefore the ancients don't take damage when you use Blade fury on them because they are magic immune and your physical attacks are doing no damage.

Roshan on the other hand has 75% magic resistance as well as a fair amount of health regeneration, making Blade Fury do minimal damage.

Although Blade Fury doesn't make your physical attacks totally useless while in Blade Fury, if you have an orb effect (a unique attack modifier) such as Eye of Skadi, the slow from the orb will still be applied to them. However, be aware of orbs that are also blocked by magic immunity (such as Chain Lightning from Maelstorm or Mjollnir).

A list of orbs that go through magic immunity:

- Desolator's Corruption
- Eye of Skadi's Cold Attack
- Any lifesteal (although if you're doing no damage this won't really help you)
- Orb of Venom's Poison Attack

And for completeness sake, there are two other orbs that go through magic immunity:

- Lone Druid's Spirit Bear's Entangling Claws
- Ursa'a Fury Swipes

Furthermore, I said that it will make your attacks do no damage against most targets, however there are some exceptions to this. If the target is a structure (towers, Undying's tombstone), mechanical unit (catapults), or a ward, then they will take normal damage as if you weren't in Blade Fury.

Comment: You can attack units during Blade Fury (and damage them) if they're unaffected by Blade Fury. Try it against a Tower or Catapult, for example.

Comment: @Decency Made the fix, Blade Fury still does no damage unless it is against specific targets, such as catapults or towers

Comment: Its not about the regen, Ancient creeps have very less regen still they are not damaged

Comment: @PremAnand Ancient Creeps are immune to magic damage. I'm unsure if you can attack and damage them while using the spell.

Comment: @PremAnand The problem with Blade Fury vs Ancients isn't their regen, they are magic immune so they don't take damage from Blade Fury

Comment: @Decency I tested it against Ancients, they don't take any damage, things that have magic immunity don't take damage from Blade Fury, even if you are attacking them while in Blade Fury. So that includes heroes with BKB, ancients, mud golems, Lifestealer's Rage, etc.

Comment: @LagAttack I kno that they are immune to damage but wat about the physical damage caused yurnero?

Comment: ^^ i mean they are immune to magical damage. FYI Ancient Dragon takes physical damage eventhough they are immune to magic.

Answer (score 0):

Roshan isn't immune to the magic damage from Bladefury (or anything else), but he has 75% resistance and lots of health regeneration so the damage is barely noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Magic immune targets are not damaged by Blade Fury itself but can be damaged by normal attacks from the spell caster in Blade Fury.

Roshan is not immune to Blade Fury, but his resistance to magic is 75% macking you think that he is immune. So if you are 'normal' attacking a non-magic immune target while you are under Blade Fury, it will do no damage.

Blade Fury >> Magic Immune = Can be damaged with normal attack.
Blade Fury >> No magic immunity = Cannot be damaged with normal attack.